# Hide cell-value in GridView untill the cell is clicked

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to develop a `GridView` in ASP.NET that connects to the `DataBase`, but displays all the cells with a "mask" that the end user will need to click to reveal the true value.
The mask can be a `hyperlink` or `button` or an `imagebutton`"  that will say click to reveal.

So a 3 by 3 `GridView` will have the 9 cells with this mask, only when one cell is clicked the true underlying value will be displayed.

The following diagram is the idea that i will have to generate using asp.net `GridView` or some other better way. I will like to have the data from the connected `DataBase`, populate the `gridview`, however, each of the cells should be masked with either a button or link, that allows the end user to view only data that they want to see. 
Once cell is clicked, then the true value is revealed to the end user.
initially all cells will be hidden with this "click to view", and the user will have to reveal only the information that he want.

I am using asp.net VB.NET or C# to develop a web app for this grid.

Comment: Nice requirement. What have you tried, did you encounter a specific problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it like this:

Make a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GV_Cells" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BTN_Id" CssClass="value-toggle" Text="Show value" /> 
                <asp:Label ID="LBL_Id" Runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Style="display:none" CssClass="value"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="SecretValue1" HeaderText="SecretValue1" ReadOnly="True" />  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SecretValue2" HeaderText="SecretValue2" ReadOnly="True" /> 
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Run a javascript at page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.value-toggle').click(function (event) {
            $('#' + event.target.id).toggle();
            $('#' + event.target.id).next('.value').toggle();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

The javascript will assign an onclick event handler to every button with class 'value-toggle', which will toggle the visibility of element that was clicked, and the next element in DOM tree that has the 'value' css class (which is the label with your value).

You can do the same for other columns - just wrap the value container with element that has the 'value' css class.

This is done on the client only - without postback. If postback is what you want (you want to track which values were shown), that would be a slightly different approach.

Comment: Thank you Pafka, Works perfectly and answer the question. Wonderful.